# Capture all consecutive all-caps words with regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match all consecutive all caps words/phrases using regex in Python. Given the following:

```
    text = "The following words are ALL CAPS. The following word is in CAPS."
```

The code would return:

```
    ALL CAPS, CAPS
```

I am currently using:

```
    matches = re.findall('[A-Z\s]+', text, re.DOTALL)
```

But this returns:

```
    ['T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ALL CAPS', ' T', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' CAPS']
```

I clearly don't want the punctuation or the 'T'. I want to return only consecutive words or a single word that only include all capital letter.

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect when the words aren't separated by a space like `ABC.DEF`?

Comment: Why do you use the option `re.DOTALL` since there is no dot in your pattern?

Comment: It was just copied in from another command. It doesn't change the output though. Very new to regex, so certainly not doing this right.

Comment: I'm confused, your question asks for `consecutive all-caps words` but your example of results you want indicates you're just looking for **any** all-caps words.

Comment: should have been more clear- I want to capture all words in all caps, but if they are consecutive, I want them to be returned as a phrase, not individuals words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one does the job:

```
import re
text = "tHE following words aRe aLL CaPS. ThE following word Is in CAPS."
matches = re.findall(r"(\b(?:[A-Z]+[a-z]?[A-Z]*|[A-Z]*[a-z]?[A-Z]+)\b(?:\s+(?:[A-Z]+[a-z]?[A-Z]*|[A-Z]*[a-z]?[A-Z]+)\b)*)",text)
print matches
```

**Output:**

```
['tHE', 'aLL CaPS', 'ThE', 'Is', 'CAPS']
```

**Explanation:**

```
(           : start group 1
  \b        : word boundary
  (?:       : start non capture group
    [A-Z]+  : 1 or more capitals
    [a-z]?  : 0 or 1 small letter
    [A-Z]*  : 0 or more capitals
   |        : OR
    [A-Z]*  : 0 or more capitals
    [a-z]?  : 0 or 1 small letter
    [A-Z]+  : 1 or more capitals
  )         : end group
  \b        : word boundary
  (?:       : non capture group
    \s+     : 1 or more spaces
    (?:[A-Z]+[a-z]?[A-Z]*|[A-Z]*[a-z]?[A-Z]+) : same as above
    \b      : word boundary
  )*        : 0 or more time the non capture group
)           : end group 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Accepted the answer. This works perfect. Any chance you could help with adding a flag to *allow* (not require) one lowercase character in the captured string? I think to require one lowercase would be something like '(?=.*[a-z]) ', but I want to get phrases/words like this- 'ALL CaPS' or 'CaPS' as well, but also 'ALL CAPS', CAPS'. Thanks again

Comment: @BHudson: Must the words begin with a capital? What about `The` at the begining of the string?

Comment: They need not begin with a capital, but all but one character should be in caps. I have a huge document where names are in all caps, but many are misspelled. I am extracting all the names and will use fuzzy matching to correct them. Some incorrectly have a single lowercase letter. So, I need to match 'tHE' or 'ThE', but not 'The' (my likely use will be 'JOhN SMITh' or 'jOHN SMiTH'). Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Perfect. Appreciate the explanation.

Comment: @BHudson: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to upvote ;-)

Comment: Best regex walk through I've seen yet.  Well done @Toto.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is relying on explicit conditions(space after letters).

```
matches = re.findall(r"([A-Z]+\s?[A-Z]+[^a-z0-9\W])",text)
```

Capture A to Z repetitions if there are no trailing lowercase or none-alphabet character.

Comment: OP says "ALL CAPS" should be 1 match group, and you missed the word A case

Comment: @Tezra Edited to meet requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your regex, you can use `strip()` and `filter`:

```
string = "The following words are ALL CAPS. The following word is in CAPS."
result = filter(None, [x.strip() for x in re.findall(r"\b[A-Z\s]+\b", string)])
# ['ALL CAPS', 'CAPS']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to start and end on a letter, and only include letters and whitespace

```
\b([A-Z][A-Z\s]*[A-Z]|[A-Z])\b
```

|[A-Z] to capture just I or A